# Why won't my if/else statement return an alert?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run JavaScript in such a way that a sum of numbers that is put in on a webpage will return an alert based on the sum. For some reason, it won't return either results' alert.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function myfunction() { 
    var first = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
    var second = document.getElementById("textbox2").value; 
    var answer = parseFloat(first)+parseFloat(second);

    var textbox3 = document.getElementById('textbox3');
    textbox3.value=answer;
} 

function calc(myfunction) {
    if (textbox3.value >= 50) {
        alert ("Congratulations!! You won!");
    } else if (textbox3.value < 50) {
        alert ("Better luck next time...");
    }
}
```

I tried to present it in the way that I've built and indented it, so hopefully this will help whoever has an idea for me.

Edit: Here's the html code that's calling the function:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" /> + <input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" /> 

<input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" onclick="myfunction()" value="=" />

<br/>

Your answer is:

<input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3"/>
```

Comment: Where is the code that calls `calc()`? That's the only place I see an alert and nothing in the code here calls that function.

Comment: why does `calc` take `myfunction` as an argument?

Comment: And if `calc()` was called, `textbox3` would be undefined in it.

Comment: You really need to read up on how scope works in JavaScript. What you have *could* work, depending on how you call the functions, but is far from best practise and probably isn't how you think it works.

Comment: @forgivenson — It wouldn't … because of the stupid inherited-from-ie4 rules on how any element with an id gets a matching global variable.

Comment: I see.. you all bring up good points. How would you suggest that I fix this?

Comment: Step 1, show us the code we all asked for. How are you calling your functions?

Comment: Thank you for the posted code, but no where in there do you call the function `calc()`. Writing a function does nothing unless you call it.

Comment: Well, I'm still learning... could you give me an example of where calc() would be called and how..?

Comment: @Quentin wow, I never knew that. I honestly didn't believe you at first, but I tried it and you are correct... and it is indeed a stupid rule. I can't believe they haven't removed that yet. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling the calc() function.  The easiest way to make this work is the following.  The changes are...

1) I have renamed your functions - get into good habits of naming functions after what they do - don't use myFunction!

2) calculateTotal() now *returns* the answer.  Within the displayWinAlert() function we store this returned result within the "total" variable.

3) I changed your "if else" to just an "else" - there is no need to test if it is lower than 50 when we have already tested the opposite.

4) Your button now calls the displayWinAlert() function when it is clicked.

Javascript:

```
function calculateTotal() { 
    var first = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
    var second = document.getElementById("textbox2").value; 
    var answer = parseFloat(first)+parseFloat(second);

    var textbox3 = document.getElementById('textbox3');
    textbox3.value=answer;
    return answer;
} 

function displayWinAlert() {
    var total = calculateTotal();
    if (total >= 50) {
        alert ("Congratulations!! You won!");
    } else {
        alert ("Better luck next time...");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" /> + <input type="text" name="textbox2" id="textbox2" /> 

<input type="submit" name="button" id="button1" onclick="displayWinAlert()" value="=" />

<br/>

Your answer is:

<input type="text" name="textbox3" id="textbox3"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This was exactly what I needed, and now my code works~!

Answer (score -1):

You're running out of scope.

textbox3 is declared in the scope of myfunction(), and you are trying to access it in another function ( calc() );

You need to declare it on calc() too.

Comment: So do I need to completely rewrite the second block of text?